# GTM UA Tag - Track Page Views using All Clicks OR All Pages as triggers

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm still learning GTM, so please forgive me if this is a basic question. I've been researching but can't find anyone with a similar issue.

What I want is simple: to set up GTM to track page views in UA. (Easy enough.) But I looked at the setup of my predecessor, and he had the UA tag set up like this:

Tag Type: Google Analytics (UA)
Track Type: Page View
(GA ID)

Triggering:
All Clicks (All Elements)
OR
All Pages (Page View)

**I'm trying to understand why they set it up with the All Clicks trigger.** What I fear is that this is recording a page view every time a click is recorded, but I can't imagine my predecessor would have created a strange setup like that. I'd just as soon eliminate the All Clicks trigger, but I don't want to harm any of our future data without fully understanding. Bottom line question: is there any good reason for this tag to be set up this way, or is it wrongly inflating my numbers? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's kind of weird.

If the tag is for tracking pageView. **The trigger should only be all page**.

Still there might be 1% that your predecessor really knows what he or she is doing.

Maybe you can share the website and we can check if it is abnormal or not.

---

Update about the click trigger

The website is firing "Pageview" when click the link.

You can change the GA tag from pageview to event and set up like this

Category : click

Action : link_click

Label : {{the click Url}}

Then you can see which user is doing pageview and who clicks the link.

Comment: It looks like there are double pageview firing on the website. One from GoogleTagManager and another from the website directly. If the GTM is working fine then you can remove the GA code directly. Double pageview will cause you very low bounce rate.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look! I'm not sure about that All Clicks trigger, but as long as GTM seems to be counting accurately, I think I'll leave it be and go ahead and remove the GA.

Comment: Yes no worry. But still there is a problem about firing pageview with click trigger. That can be removed either. Or if we want to make it right. You can change it from pageview to an event maybe call click_link

Comment: Gotcha, I appreciate the edit with the extra info on fixing the click trigger. At this point, I'm wanting to just remove the clicks trigger. And I will solely be tracking page views at that point, yes? Thanks for working through this with me as a rookie.

Comment: Yes. you can try to remove it and preview to test the pageview should be working fine.